# what to do to insert 10000 number elements in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have tried to enter 10000 elements, but I'm unable to insert more than 1 element:

```
for( i = 0; i< 10000; ++i)
{
    db.posts.insert({"Student_id" : i, "Name" : "Mark"});
}
```

Comment: What application and version are you using, and how are you confirming if the documents were inserted? Your example code is missing a declaration of `i` so I would have expected this to result in an "i is not defined" reference error.

Comment: I have tried by declaring var i but still it showing nInserted : 1

Comment: Have you tried viewing the collection or running `db.posts.count()`? You haven't mentioned your application or version used, but since you don't have any `print()` statements it is possible that the output is only showing the results of the last statement executed (which would be a single `insert()`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Studio3T works, but I can add 10k elements using the Node driver. The only difference is I have to do `db.collection('posts').insert(...)`. Anyway, the correct method would be to create a list containing the documents first and insert all of them with [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)